# Haskell Yesod - extracting a object inside a json before converting it to a model

Tags: haskell, yesod, aeson

Suppose I have a JSON like this:

```
{
  data: {...}
}
```

and `{...}` represents a model of mine. How could 
get my model in this case in the Handler? For instance, the following will not work obviously:

```
putMyEntityR :: Handler ()
putMyEntityR = do
  (Entity id _) <- (...) -- getting the Key
  e <- requireJsonBody :: Handler MyEntity
  runDB $ replace id e
  sendResponseStatus status204 ("UPDATED" :: Text)
```

How can I read the `JSON`, take the `data` object, and only then decode it?

Comment: I think the obvious way would be to use a simple wrapper and make it an instance of `FromJSON`

Comment: I am not familiar with Yesod, but have you considered [aeson-lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-aeson-1.0.0.5/docs/Data-Aeson-Lens.html) ? The doc on Hackage gives you a pretty nice idea of what you can do. You don't need to provide a parser; you just lookup (or do any lens magic you want with) the json field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was some more discussion of this question on a [Github Issue](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/issues/1177), which I'm adding as an answer here because it's more fleshed out. Here's what we arrive at for the Handler function using the helper functions defined below:

```
postDataCommentR :: Handler Value
postDataCommentR = do
  value <- requireJsonBody' -- Parse request body into Value
  commentJson <- requireJsonKey "data" value -- Lookup a key from the Value
  comment <- (requireJsonParse commentJson :: Handler Comment) -- Parse the Value into a comment record

  insertedComment <- runDB $ insertEntity comment
  returnJson insertedComment
```

These functions take the request body and parse it into an aeson `Value`:

```
import qualified Data.Aeson as J
import qualified Data.Aeson.Parser as JP
import Data.Conduit.Attoparsec (sinkParser)

-- These two functions were written by @FtheBuilder
parseJsonBody' :: (MonadHandler m) => m (J.Result Value)
parseJsonBody' = do
    eValue <- rawRequestBody $$ runCatchC (sinkParser JP.value')
    return $ case eValue of
        Left e -> J.Error $ show e
        Right value -> J.Success value

-- | Same as 'parseJsonBody', but return an invalid args response on a parse
-- error.
requireJsonBody' :: (MonadHandler m) => m Value
requireJsonBody' = do
    ra <- parseJsonBody'
    case ra of
        J.Error s -> invalidArgs [pack s]
        J.Success a -> return a
```

These helper functions are used to parse that `Value` into a record:

```
requireJsonParse :: (MonadHandler m, FromJSON a) => Value -> m a
requireJsonParse v = case J.fromJSON v of
  J.Error s -> invalidArgs [pack s]
  J.Success a -> return a

requireJsonKey :: (MonadHandler m) => Text -> Value -> m Value
requireJsonKey key jObject@(Object hashMap) = case lookup key hashMap of
                                    Nothing -> invalidArgs ["Couldn't find a value when looking up the key " <> key <> " in the object: " <> (pack (show jObject))]
                                    Just v -> return v
requireJsonKey key invalid = invalidArgs ["When looking up the key " <> key <> ", expected an object but got a " ++ (pack (show invalid))]
```

### Commentary

#### aeson-lens

I didn't use `aeson-lens`, but the code is pretty similar with or without it, since we're just going one key deep. `aeson-lens` would make things nicer if we were traversing deeper into the JSON.

#### Comparison to wrapper definition

Once you get the helper functions defined, you still have a couple lines to parse a `Value`, then lookup the `data` key, then create your record. You can do things to make this shorter, but ultimately the wrapper that @Carsten recommended would be of similar length with less complexity, imo.

Comment: You can bind this functions into one, which will take a single like.

Comment: That's a good point, this is pretty clean: `(comment :: Comment) <- requireJsonBody' >>= requireJsonKey "data" >>= requireJsonParse`

Answer (score 2):

This was too large to fit in my comment above (using [lens-aeson](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-aeson-1.0.0.5/docs/Data-Aeson-Lens.html))

```
λ: import Control.Lens
λ: import Data.Aeson.Lens
λ: let e = "{ \"data\": [1,2,3] }"
λ: e ^? key "data"
Just (Array [Number 1.0,Number 2.0,Number 3.0])
```

and as Carsten mentioned, you'll still need to provide a FromJSON instance of your model

Comment: while this is a nice way to do it I don't think it will work as is with `requireJsonBody` - that's why I would write a simple `data Wrapper = Wrapper { data :: MyEntity }` and make it an instance - the instance for `MyEntity` should already be there - yesod handles these things using TH

Comment: The [implementation](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.5/yesod-core-1.4.19/src/Yesod-Core-Json.html#requireJsonBody) of `requireJsonBody` is really short though. You could write your own function that parsed an aeson `Value` and if parsing failed threw an `invalidArgs ` exception

Comment: This is very likely negligible for @FtheBuilder's use case, but I think  using a small wrapper would be more memory/CPU efficient because aeson could parse a `ByteString` [directly into the record as of aeson-0.10](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.11.1.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#g:7), whereas with aeson-lens you're working with the intermediate `Value` data structure. Again, though, likely negligible for most use cases.

Comment: I'm glad I posted this answer, I learnt more than I was able to share! thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Carsten - Your way is interesting, but it would require to write a lot of simple Wrappers (because it is a pattern which will appear frequently)... I think that only extracting the part that I need and then using it is a better approach in my case...That's why I liked Nicolas Mattia's comment.