# If it is possible to define locally data type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, yesod

Recentlly, I find an interesting question when I'am writing some code in haskell.

For example, in the yesod framework, if i need to write a route to parse json parameters, I need to define a data type like this:

```
data Args = Args { a :: Int }
instance FromJSON Args where
putSampleR :: Handler ()
putSampleR = do
    Args{..} <- requireJsonBody
    <balabalabala>
```

It works fine. 
But it becomes pulzzled if I have a lot of these routes which need a parameters to be parsed.

I may have Args1, Args2, Args3 and there field must be different, so 
Args1{a1}, Args2{a2}, Args3{a3}

It is very annoying to me.

So, if it is possible that I write my code like this way:

```
putSampleR :: Handler ()
putSampleR = do
    Args{..} <- requireJsonBody
    <balabalabala>
  where
    data Args = Args { a :: Int }
    instance FromJSON Args where
```

To define data variables locally?

Comment: It is not possible to define types locally, but maybe there's some alternative. (I don't have one at the moment)

Comment: Sounds like you might be interested in `DuplicateRecordFields` extension and related ones.

Comment: You don't have to create a new data type to pull values from JSON. See this question and both answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35816074/1176156

Comment: @jd823592 DuplicateRecordFields only avaiable in ghc8 ... Quite close to my need, but the really excited one is just the above 'locally defined' one. It is achived in idris [http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html#where-clauses] already.

Comment: @MaxGabriel nice thread.